# How to inject groovyPageRenderer properties in grails utils package

Tags: spring, grails, dependency-injection

I want to create a builder in grails utils package. Unlike service and controler, the class in grails utils package is out of the normal scope.

So I have code like this:

```
class XxxBuilder {

    def groovyPageRenderer

    public String build(def quoteNumber) {
        def xmlRequest = groovyPageRenderer.render(view: '/xml/requestTemplate')

        xmlRequest
    }
}
```

I also write some code in resources.groovy, like
    groovyPageRenderer(PageRenderer)

```
xxxBuilder(XxxBuilder){
     groovyPageRenderer=ref(groovyPageRenderer)
}
```

As the builder will invoked by grails service.

However, given this code I write some integration test for this, it throws some exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groovyPageRenderer': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [grails.gsp.PageRenderer]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: grails.gsp.PageRenderer.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:983)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:102)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at TestApp$_run_closure1.doCall(TestApp.groovy:32)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [grails.gsp.PageRenderer]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: grails.gsp.PageRenderer.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1030)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: grails.gsp.PageRenderer.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78)
    ... 39 more
```

Someone knows how to inject it properly in grails?

Comment: You mean grails-app/utils? That's for codecs. Put utility classes in src/groovy. The intention years ago was that the utils folder would contain minor artifact classes that didn't merit their own folder, but there weren't more introduced other than codecs. This doesn't affect your question, but it's a common mistake.

Comment: can you post the service code too?

Comment: @Burt Beckwith, if I put the code in src/groovy, will this work instead of declare dependencies?

Comment: @FabianoTaioli I don't have the service code yet. Only this. I don't think the problem is related to service.

Comment: No, moving it to src/groovy doesn't change that you can't auto-dependency-inject, but it's the correct location

Comment: In the service you declare xxxBuilder as field? And you don't instantiate it with new XxxBuilder() right?